# How to write the constraints for scipy SLSQP properly

Tags: python, constraints, scipy-optimize, minimize, boundary

I am trying to write an optimization code with constraints using SLSQP method. But I can't understand it enough to write the proper codes for constraints.

Lets say we have a function *f*, with *p* parameters, all with the same starting values (**0.1**) and `arg` is the array of these parameters:

```
arg = [.1] * p
```

Here I want `sum(arg[2:])` to be less than 1, and `arg[i] > 0` for the optimization. How can i write the constraints/boundaries for `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

minimize( fun = f,
          x0  = arg,
          method = 'SLSQP',
          constraints = ?,
          bounds = ?
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't use strict inequality constraints like g(x) < 1 or x > 0. Instead, you can model them by g(x) ≥ 1 - ε and x ≤ ε, where ε is a sufficiently small positive constant. In addition, if `args` is your starting point, i.e. the vector consisting of 1s only, then there's no constraint as `sum(c)` doesn't depend on your any optimization variable. I take it you'd like to add the constraint that the sum of all the optimization variables (except the first two ones) is smaller than 1:

Note that scipy expects each equality constraint in the form g(x) = 0 and each inequality constraint in the form g(x) ≥ 0. Therefore, you can define your first constraint by

```py
def con_fun(x, eps = 1.0e-8):
    # np.sum(x[2:]) ≤ 1 - eps
    # (np.sum(x[2:]) - 1 + eps ≤ 0
    # 1 - eps - np.sum(x[2:]) ≥ 0
    return 1 - eps - np.sum(x[2:])

constrs = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con_fun})
```

Your second constraints are simple bounds on the optimization variables, thus

```py
eps = 1.0e-8
# 0 + eps <= x[i] < ∞
bounds = [(0 + eps, None) for _ in range(p)]
```

Finally, you can can call the minimize method:

```py
minimize(your_obj_fun, x0=x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=constrs, bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: At first, I accepted this answer because it seemed ok. However after a research I learnt there is actually no need for an epsilon. The standard and simplest way to write this constraint is:

`constrs = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - sum(arg[2:])}]`

So your answer is ok but this "*you can't use strict inequality constraints*" statement is not true.

Comment: @ErdemŞen Well, your 'standard' way models `sum(arg[2:])) ≤ 1`, not the **strict** inequality `sum(arg[2:])) < 1` as asked in your initial question. If you really wanted the former, there's indeed no need for an epsilon. However, in that case your question was misleading since "*Here I want sum(arg[2:]) to be less than 1, and arg[i] > 0*" both ask for **strict** inequalities. There's a huge difference between `<` and `≤` (resp. less-than and less-than-or-equal) from a mathematical point of view. That being said, my statement regarding strict inequalities is still true.

Comment: I see. it is my question, misleading. A fix on that (reediting my question) would also make your answer seem wrong, though. So i will keep it as it is. Thank you